# buttons generated in php and javascript calling a javascript function with an argument just refresh the page

Tags: php, javascript, html

I am trying to generate some buttons to hide a text field on a form with php and javascript, but every time i press the button it just refreshes the page. I cant tell if its the buttons or the function that is having troubles but i am assuming the program is refreshing because it is erroring out.

php generated button

```
echo("<button id=\"button".$count."\" onclick=deleteAnswer(answer".$count."); return            false;>delete answer</button>");
```

javascript generated function

```
write.innerHTML = write.innerHTML + "<button id=\"button"+answers+"\" onclick=\"deleteAnswer(\"answer"+answers+"\")\"; return false;>delete answer</button>";
```

actual javascript function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function deleteAnswer(button)
{
    document.getElementById(button).style.visibility="hidden";
}
</script>
```

Comment: Your `onclick` attribute in JS has the quotes in the wrong place and also uses nested double quotes, which will not work. Your `onclick` attribute should be in double quotes in the PHP version as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have Several Issues `answer".$count."` and `"answer"+answers+"\"` has to be wrapped in qoutes  and

```
echo("<button id=\"button".$count."\" onclick=deleteAnswer('answer".$count."'); return            false;>delete answer</button>");


write.innerHTML = write.innerHTML + "<button id=\"button"+answers+"\" onclick=\"deleteAnswer(\"answer"+answers+"\"); return false;">delete answer</button>"
```

and

```
 document.getElementById(button).style.visibility="hidden";
```

has to be

```
 document.getElementById(button).style.display="hidden";
```

OR

```
 document.getElementById(button).style.visibility="visible";
```

Comment: i tried making the changes you have above, but the quotes seem to be incorrect, i tried changing them so that they worked but im still not having any luck with it

Comment: place your generated html on jsfiddle

Comment: i have it printing this as source code now                      <button id="button0" onclick="deleteAnswer(answer0);" return="" false;"="">delete answer</button>

Comment: replace this onclick=\"deleteAnswer(\"answer"+answers+"\"); return false;"

Comment: so i can now click the button when i generate it like this in the php echo("<button id=\"button".$count."\" onclick=\"deleteAnswer('answer".$count."'); return false;\">delete answer</button>");  (its only generating it in the php right now, i commented out the javascript button generator) but now the buttons just dont do anything

Comment: place an alert inside delete and alert your button param.

Comment: i got it working, fyi, it is visibility, not display. thanks for all the help!